# Why does this not work? Program in C

Tags: c

The program I am writing is in C. It is supposed to have the user input a distance, and then calculate the angle at which you would need to shoot a projectile to reach that said distance, at a set velocity:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MuzzleVelocity  1000
#define PI (3.141592653589793)
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  float G, meters, tf, angle, range;
  G = 9.8; /* M/sec^2  */
  printf("Enter the range of Enemy Sub in Meters>");
  scanf("%f", &meters);
  printf("\nTo hit the sub at %f meters", meters);
  angle = (180/PI)* .5* asin(range / ((pow(MuzzleVelocity, 2))/G));
  printf ("\n Use the angle %f degrees", angle);
  return 0;
}
```

If anyone could explain the line beginning with int main as well, that would be extremely helpful, I mainly edited the beginning from a previous problem, and substituted the variables I thought I needed to input. The correct output should be:

```
Enter the range of Enemy sub in Meters> XXX.XX
To hit the sub at XXX.XX meters
Use the angle XX.XX
```

Comment: Put `\n` at end (not beginning) of every `printf` format control string. Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`).  Use the debugger (`gdb`). Test result of [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html). Read the documentation of every function that you are using.

Comment: aruisdante seems to have the correct answer; I'd also suggest you look into the difference between integer and floating point constants. In this case you get away with it due to type promotion but e.g. if you had `(1/3)* <something>` then I think your expectations might be thwarted.

Comment: Since you don't use any command-line arguments, you could write `int main(void)`. If you did, you'd want `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`; the `const` makes sense, but it's non-standard.

Comment: "If anyone could explain the line beginning with int main" -- That's best done by taking a class in C programming, reading textbooks and tutorials, and other forms of instruction. SO is not a good substitute for an education in the basics.

Answer (score 4):

The problem (though you never actually tell us what 'not working' means) is likely that you are assigning the user input to `meters`:

```
printf("Enter the range of Enemy Sub in Meters>");
scanf("%f", &meters);
```

But then in your equations, you use the value of `range`, which has not been set to any value, and will thus have a completely random value in it:

```
angle = (180/PI)* .5* asin(range / ((pow(MuzzleVelocity, 2))/G));
```

Replace `range` with `meters` in the equation, or vise-versa in the `scanf`.

Comment: Thanks this worked! As a side note, I kind of guessed at the top, in the int main section, where I added meters, angle, and range. It came out alright, but is the purpose of that to simply state all the variables that will be used in the main function?

Comment: @user1877731 please accept the answer if it solved your problem (the big checkmark next to the question). What exactly do you mean by *'in the int main section'*? `int main (int argc, const char * argv[])` is the C-standard definition of a ``main`` that can accept parameters passed to it via the launching process (typically the command-line).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your pow function doesn't know which instance to call. MuzzleVelocity should be double, float or long double. You can just put 
pow float((MuzzleVelocity), 2).

Secondly you don't give any value to range and you use it to calculate angle. I guess you made the mistake and wanted to get range in meters as input and not meters. If I am correct you should change  scanf("%f", &meters); to  scanf("%f", &range);

Hope that